# Setting a featured image while creating the post

Tags: wp-insert-post, wp-update-post

I am creating a post with wp_insert_post/wp_update_post. The post should have a featured image. But to set a featured image I need the postID. The problem is I do not have any postID.
What I am doing is. I create a "profile page" for every user. Therefore the user just updates his data in the backend. The post is created automatically out of the data.

I tied things like:

```
set_post_thumbnail( wp_insert_post($post), $thumbnail_id );
```

But is does not work. 
Surprisingly `set_post_thumbnail( wp_update_post($post), $thumbnail_id );` works. But in case I want to create a pot the first time, I need wp_insert_post.

I can provide the full code on request.
Any ideas?

Thanks and regards
Nico

Comment: `wp_insert_post` and `wp_update_post` return the post id when you use it, so you can use the id for stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't add the thumbnail in the first array you send to create the post, you'll need to grab the post ID after the wp_insert_post, then run update_post_meta after the first part of the function.

If you post your function here we might be able to help a little further.

Comment: But how is it done from wordpress itself? If I create a post in the Admin area I can set a featured image while creating the post. Perhaps I could just copy and modify this action..?

Comment: In WordPress, an id is established the second you click add new post. If you post your function here we can help.